# WSO2, datamapper mediator fails with "[base64 string] is not defined in <eval> at line number 1"

Tags: json, wso2

On both Integration Studio 8.0.0 and Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0 i'm having an error when using a datamapper mediator to convert a JSON payload to another JSON payload.
The error has the base64 conversion of the datamapper .dmc file.

A full log mediator placed before the datamapper shows that I received a correct json response

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,076] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Start : Log mediator
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,076]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:8f511c89-c468-4f24-a067-d0f476a63fb7, Direction: response, Payload: (the whole json response)
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,077] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - End : Log mediator
```

The full error is

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,077] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - Building message. Sequence <SequenceMediator> is content aware
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} - Content Type is application/json; charset=UTF-8
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,078]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Local entry : gov:datamappers/ricercaUoDataMapper.dmc was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,082]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Local entry : gov:datamappers/ricercaUoDataMapper_inputSchema.json was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,084]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Local entry : gov:datamappers/ricercaUoDataMapper_outputSchema.json was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,100] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapsePropertiesLoader} - Retrieving synapse properties from the cache
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,102] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonReadOnlyStream} - #close
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:01,580] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator} - DataMapper mediator : mapping failed Error while reading input stream. Script engine unable to execute the script javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "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" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputReader.read(JSONInputReader.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.InputBuilder.buildInputModel(InputBuilder.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.core.mapper.MappingHandler.doMap(MappingHandler.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:390)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMapperMediator.java:301)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:380)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:58)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:327)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:578)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:195)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:284)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,307]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_CODE : 0
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,308]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_MESSAGE : DataMapper mediator : mapping failed
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,308]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: DataMapper mediator : mapping failed
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator.handleException(AbstractMediator.java:367)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:444)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMapperMediator.java:301)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:380)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:58)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:327)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:578)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:195)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:284)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Error while reading input stream. Script engine unable to execute the script javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "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" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputReader.read(JSONInputReader.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.InputBuilder.buildInputModel(InputBuilder.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.core.mapper.MappingHandler.doMap(MappingHandler.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:390)
    ... 18 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,309]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: DataMapper mediator : mapping failed
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,309]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - FaultHandler : org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler@11271f01
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,309]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler} - Executing fault handler mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,309] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - Start : Sequence <anonymous>
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,309] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - Sequence <SequenceMediator> :: mediate()
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,309] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - Mediation started from mediator position : 0
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-09-08 13:43:02,310] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - End : Sequence <anonymous>
```

The whole interaction happens with a `Accept: application/json` header, but it happens even with a xml -> json datamapping.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the payload is json why are you using xml->json data mapping? should it not be json->json data mapping?
2. Accept:application/json header means it would be json so ideally you should use json->json mapping

Comment: As I said, the payload is json->json, but it happens with xml->json too.

Comment: I may be able to help as I have been using WSO2 extensively but would have to see your implementation. Is there any way we can do that?

Comment: Eh, sadly because of this issue I had to change my implementation, I don't have anymore the faulty code